# ggsurvplot (Survminer) Customising the title (adding italics)

Tags: ggplot2, title, survival-analysis, italics, survminer

I am looking to customise my ggsurvplot title by making one word in it be in italics.
I have tried the more 'classic' code that words in ggplots, but they don't appear to work in this.

Here is an example of what I am doing:

```
library(survival)
library(survminer)

fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)
plt1 <- ggsurvplot(fit, data =lung, title = "Adding *italics* to the Title")
plt1
[plt1 ][1]
plt2 <-  ggsurvplot(fit, data =lung, title = "Adding <i>italics</i> to the Title")
plt2

[plt2][1]
```

They then just copy the title directly as I have written it so no italics! D:
Looking forward to any help I can get.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `expression` like this:

```
ggsurvplot(fit, data =lung, title = expression(paste("Adding ", italic("italics"), " to a title")))
```

That gives
[image]